# Equation to find constant Acceleration using Distance, Initial Velocity and Final Velocity variables.

Tags: calculus

I am attempting to find the Acceleration of a vehicle but only have the Initial Velocity, Final Velocity and the Distance travelled. All equations I have found require the time taken to travel this distance, but assuming a consistent acceleration, it it possible to find this value?

The vehicle starts at 10 miles per hour (4.4704 meters per second), travels 116 meters while constantly accelerating, and is travelling 100 miles per hour (44.704 meters per second) by the time it reaches the finish.

Comment: See [Uniform accelerated motion](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/physics/uniformly-accelerated-motion-calculator.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you want to use is $$v^2=u^2+2as,$$
where $v$ is the final velocity, $u$ is the initial velocity, $a$ is the constant acceleration, and $s$ is the displacement from the initial position.

See e.g. [Help with Physics question, show that: $v^2 = u^2+2as$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919106/help-with-physics-question-show-that-v2-u22as) for hints on how to prove this.

Comment: In other words, use conservation of energy.